# Databae won't open, linked table on open form is missing

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am in a pickle!  I was attempting to relink my tables to my frontend, but accidentally missed one.  That one table is important for my startup form, and since it is missing, the database just opens straight to the welcome screen.

If I can access the vba, I could change the on open event, or if I could change the start-up form, but I can't get to either of those options.  What can I do to get this fixed so I can get back to development?

I've tried holding the shift key, still nothing.  Can't get the list of tables that are in there.  And the access options > current database features are disabled.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Cannot you open your DB along with Shift Key. It should give you access to the VBA Code.

Comment: @Vikas I tried the shift key, it just goes to the access welcome screen.  Ctrl + g opens the VBA window, but no VBA projects are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!  WOO-HOO.  Instead of holding down the shift key, I held down 'F11'.  This brought up a message saying that the table was not there, when I clicked okay, I was then able to press 'F11' again, that opened the Navigation Panel.  I had access to the VBA and to the ribbon, and so I was able to just go add the linked table that was missing, and it solved my problem.

I was real nervous about losing 3 hours of work.  I backed it up this morning, but I guess I need to do it more often.  Thanks for the suggestions!